# Get Values Of Localstorage using keys

Tags: jquery, debugging

I had saved following data in localstorage

```
{
    pages: "[{"id":1443515245154,"name":"Bohemia"},{"id":1443515285226,"name":"Brand"}]"
}
```

Now I want to get values like where `id = 1443515245154` or `id = 1443515285226`. Please help me related this.

Comment: You'll need to parse the JSON in `pages`, then loop over the resulting array and check the `id` value of each object to find the one you're looking for. This is obviously on the assumption that the mis-matched quotes are a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {

    $.each(value.pages, function (index1, value1) {

        console.log(value1.id)

    })

})

var data = [{
    "pages": [{
        "id": "1443515245154",
            "name": "Bohemia"
    }, {
        "id": "1443515285226",
            "name": "Brand"
    }]
}]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gbfnmby4/)

Try this one. I fixed the data because it is not a correct json just check the data i used compare it to your data.
Check your json [here](http://jsonlint.com/) if its valid

`UPDATE`

```
var pages = data[0].pages;
console.log(pages[0].id)
console.log(pages[1].id)
```

Comment: i know about get values from each loop but i want direct value by id like php where id=11111